# How do I decode text that are 64 characters long

Tags: utf-8, base64, sha256, sha1, decoding

How can I decode a text. I have a 64 long character word that I want to decode from an sql file. At the top on the sql it says SET Client encoding UTF8. Also its in Hash Format: SHA1 & SHA-256. What steps do I need to take to decode it. Also am I missing any steps or am I not aware of something.

I tried getting some information on decoding but wasnt able to understand much.

Comment: Hashes are effectively random values. There's nothing to decode here. What are you trying to do? What is this file, what created it, and what are you trying to do with it?